# CDN fallback for jQuery-ui.min.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web app built using MVC 4, and wanted a safeguard in place against CDN fails. So in order to have this work, I set the app up to use CDN's at first go 'round, and if the CDN is down, it will fallback to local files. I am only referencing 4 jQuery files, and 3 out of the 4 are working fine and loading from the fallback local source. This one is not, however:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
```

I am sure I have the syntax correct, since it's the same way I built out the other ones, and those are working fine. Yes, I have the file "jquery-ui.min.js" in my Scripts folder, and I literally navigated to the url: https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js and copied the contents into the js file in my scripts folder, so everything is the exact same. The app is just not loading the local file when I push it to fail. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: typeof jQuery doesn't test for jquery ui, it tests for jQuery.

Comment: it doesn't throw any error when i push it to fallback on the local file. do i just need to change the typeof?

Comment: You just need to instead check for the existance of a `ui` property on `jQuery`

Comment: As an aside, you might want to try another free CDN as a fallback for production, as opposed to falling back to your own servers for the static content. For example, you're currently hitting a Microsoft CDN and could fall back to a Google one: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js. (For development, it's sometimes good to go with local still in case there is not Internet connection and you're developing locally.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of testing for jQuery to exist, test for jQuery UI to exist.

```
if (!jQuery.ui) {
    ...
```